# What will be the perimeter of the figure?

Tags: geometry

[image]

What will be the perimeter of the given figure?

**My attempt**

I have first drawn the below figure for my understanding

[image]

**Rectangle**

```
Length = 7 cm
Breadth = 4 cm
Perimeter = 2(L+B) = 2(7+4) =22 cm
```

**Circle A**

```
Radius = 4 cm
Circumference of Circle A = 2*PI* R = 2*PI *4 =8PI cm
```

**Circle B**

```
Radius = 3 cm
Circumference of Circle B = 2*PI* R = 2*PI *3 =6PI cm
```

**Circle C**

```
Radius = 1 cm
Circumference of Circle C = 2*PI* R = 2*PI *1 =2PI cm

Perimeter of the figure =   Perimeter of Rectangle + Circumference of Circle A 
+ Circumference of Circle B + Circumference of Circle C

             = 22 cm + 8PI + 6PI + 2PI cm
             = (22 +16PI) cm
             = 22+16 * (22/7) cm        [PI = 22/7 = 3.14]
             = 72.28 cm
```

**But the original answer is (12 PI + 6)cm = 43.68 cm**

Kindly guide me where I am wrong?

Comment: It is only evaluating the perimeter of the combined figure ( boundary that is accessible from outside). In other words, take out one fourth of the circle perimeter and in rectangle you only add $(7-1)$ on the bottom side of the rectangle which is on the perimeter of the combined figure.

Comment: thanks for clearing the doubt - yes Perimeter is the outer boundary  - Mistake(:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By perimeter the question refers to the outer frame of the figure.

$$6+\frac{3}{4}\cdot2\pi(4+3+1)=12\pi+6$$

[image]

Comment: great - thanks a lot